# Javascript flip image

Tags: javascript, image, flip

Does anyone know if there is any JavaScript library for image flipping. I don't want the css3 effect i want to actually flip an image as you do on image editors when right becomes left.

Comment: Do you want to mirror its bits or just to mirror its rendering?

Comment: mirror its bits but I also need it to work on IE8

Comment: It would be easy enough with a `Canvas`, but that won't work on IE8...

Comment: "mirror bits" of image that was downloaded from Web and which resides in browser cache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to flip an image is to use CSS3. I assume by "CSS3 effect" you meant an animation, and this *does not* do this.

```
img {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

This works by scaling the image by -1 on the X axis (flipping it along that axis) and 1 on the Y axis (doing nothing). If you wanted to flip on the Y axis rather than the X axis, you could switch around X and Y.

CSS3 transforms could also be used for rotating, if the need arose. Rather than `scale(-1, 1)` you could use something like `rotate(90deg)` to rotate 90 degrees clockwise.

---

For Internet Explorer support, you can use the `filter` property:

```
img {
    filter: fliph;
    /* all of the transforms above */
}
```

Comment: @FlorianShena: I added something to support IE8 that I found, but I don't have a Windows machine with IE8 on hand, so I can't test it.

Comment: This looks very useful. Can you provide an example usage on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: It is a very uninvolved technique; an example should not be necessary. However, if, for some reason, someone needs one, [here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/Annuy/).